# Pointing .htacees to node server that uses SSL configurations

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, http, ssl

I am using the following configurations in .htacess file

```
# RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:3001/$1 [P,L] 
# RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ https://127.0.0.1:3001/$1 [P,L]
```

when I add SSL configurations and use https module in the node server the URL returns 503 services not found but works fine when I remove SSL and use http module.

Comment: So what does that http server's error log file reveal what the issue is?

Comment: not found, NP! 
I fixes the issue by 
removing RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:3001/$1 [P,L]  line

thanks

Comment: What do you mean "not found"? You don't know where the location of your http server error log file is? Then how do you expect to be able to operate a web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed by removing

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:3001/$1 [P,L]
```